# How to have vectorize calculation between a 1D and 2D numpy array with if conditions

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, vectorization

I have a calculation using a 1D and a 2D numpy array. It has two levels of `if`-conditions. I was able to use `np.where` to avoid one `if`-statement and further use the slow list comprehension to iterate through each row.

Ideally, I would like to vectorize the whole calculation process. Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

r_base = np.linspace(0, 4, 5)
np.random.seed(0)
r_mat = np.array([r_base * np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.1, 5),
                  r_base * np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.1, 5),
                  r_base * np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.1, 5)])

a_array = np.linspace(1, 3, 3)

def func_vetorized_level1(r_row, a):
    if r_row.mean() > 2:
        result = np.where((r_row >= a), r_row - a, np.nan)
    else:
        result = np.where((r_row >= a), r_row + a, 0)
    return result
# try to broadcast this func to every row of r_mat using list comprehension
res_mat = np.array([func_vetorized_level1(this_r_row, this_a) 
                    for this_r_row, this_a in zip(r_mat, a_array)])
```

result is

```
res_mat =
array([[       nan, 0.04303787, 1.04110535, 2.02692991, 2.93892384],
       [       nan,        nan, 0.1567092 , 1.27819766, 1.90675322],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 6.25535798, 6.65682885]])
```

Comment: Why are you zipping something with three rows and something with five elements? Did you mean to transpose the matrix?

Comment: Oh I had a mistake, the a_array should only have three elements. I will correct it in the original post.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer. You can drop the first index in `a`.

Comment: You should to re-define `a_array` as `np.linspace(1, 3, 3)` rather than `1, 5, 3` if you want to preserve your output. Otherwise, you should update the output array.

Comment: If you want, you can always revisit your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5970929/gang?tab=questions) page to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is more vectorizable than you think. In addition to vectoring it, you can use the existing functions more appropriately.

To generate an integer range, `np.arange` works better than `np.linspace`:

```
r_base = np.arange(5.)
a_array = np.arange(1., 4.)
```

The random numbers can be made in a single call with one multiply:

```
np.random.seed(0)
r_mat = r_base * np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.1, (3, 5))
```

I think the simplest thing to do would be to make an output array and fill it based on the different conditions:

```
out = np.empty_like(r_mat)
```

It would be helpful to make `a_array` into a column that matches the number of rows in `r_mat`:

```
a = a_array[:, None]
```

The next thing you is to make masks for the conditions. The first is a row-wise mask for `r_row.mean() > 2`. The second is the element-wise `r_row >= a` condition:

```
row_mask = (r_mat.mean(axis=1) > 2)[:, None]
elem_mask = r_mat >= a
```

The index `[:, None]` on `row_mask` makes it into a column vector for broadcasting purposes. Now you can evaluate the selections using direct masking and the `where` keyword to the appropriate `ufunc`s:

```
np.subtract(r_mat, a, out=out, where=row_mask & elem_mask)
np.add(r_mat, a, out=out, where=~row_mask & elem_mask)
out[row_mask & ~elem_mask] = np.nan
out[~row_mask & ~elem_mask] = 0
```

Comment: 1) I got a value error:" operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,5)" row_mask & ~elem_mask combination is causing this problem. 2) Is it possible to use operation signs like +,-,*,/ ? my calculation could be more complex than add and subtract.

Comment: @Gang. 1) I fixed the code. `row_mask` was not a column as it should have been, and I included your new `a_array`. 2) `add` is the `ufunc` that implements `+`, `subtract` implements `-`, etc. You can do masked operations instead, like `out[some_mask] = (r_mat - a)[some_mask]`, but that would needlessly compute all the unmasked elements, then create another array of masked ones, and assign that. The way I show is much more efficient. Once you understand this way of doing it, I would be happy to help with a more complex case. I would recommend asking a different question for that though.

Comment: @Gang. The directly masked approach is only a good idea when you have functions that are not `ufuncs` that don't accept a `where`-like argument. And of course it's fine for scalar assignment, since you only evaluate one thing for that.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my previous comment, which suggested using `out[index] = (r_mat[index] -a [row_index])` to avoid calculating more elements than need. I don't know how to undo the delete so I reposted it to the context. Thank you for the great comment.

Comment: @Gang if you use the indices properly, it will work, but will still be less efficient than using ufuncs.

Comment: I posted there  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291209/conditional-vectorized-calculation-with-numpy-arrays-without-using-direct-maskin