# conditional vectorized calculation with numpy arrays without using direct masking

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, vectorization

[following up on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63277363/how-to-have-vectorize-calculation-between-a-1d-and-2d-numpy-array-with-if-condit/63277625?noredirect=1#comment111917332_63277625)

```
import numpy as np

repeat=int(1e5)
r_base = np.linspace(0,4,5)
a_base = 2
np.random.seed(0)
r_mat = r_base * np.random.uniform(0.9,1.1,(repeat,5))

a_array = a_base * np.random.uniform(0.9,1.1, repeat)


# original slow approach
def func_vetorized_level1(r_row, a):
    if r_row.mean()>2:
        result = np.where((r_row >= a), r_row - a, np.nan)
    else:
        result = np.where((r_row >= a), r_row + a, 0)
    return result
# try to broadcast this func to every row of r_mat using list comprehension
def func_list_level2(r_mat, a_array):
    res_mat = np.array([func_vetorized_level1(this_r_row, this_a) 
                        for this_r_row, this_a in zip(r_mat, a_array)])
    return res_mat

# faster with direct masking, but with unnecessary more calculation
def f_faster(r_mat,a_array):
    a = a_array[:, None]  # to column vector

    row_mask = (r_mat.mean(axis=1) > 2)[:,None]
    elem_mask = r_mat >= a

    out = np.empty_like(r_mat)

    out[row_mask & elem_mask] = (r_mat - a)[row_mask & elem_mask]
    out[~row_mask & elem_mask] = (r_mat + a)[~row_mask & elem_mask]
    out[row_mask & ~elem_mask] = np.nan
    out[~row_mask & ~elem_mask] = 0
    
    return out

# fastest with ufunc in numpy as suggested by @mad_physicist
def f_fastest(r_mat,a_array):
    a = a_array[:, None]  # to column vector

    row_mask = (r_mat.mean(axis=1) > 2)[:,None]
    elem_mask = r_mat >= a

    out = np.empty_like(r_mat)


    np.subtract(r_mat, a, out=out, where=row_mask & elem_mask)
    np.add(r_mat, a, out=out, where=~row_mask & elem_mask)
    out[row_mask & ~elem_mask] = np.nan
    out[~row_mask & ~elem_mask] = 0
    
    return out
```

I would like to ask if it is possible to have a user-defined func that can be used, or take advantage of the fastest approach? I thought about using indexing but found it is challenging, because the sliced elements using `[row_ind, co_ind]` is a 1d array of the selected elements. I see the sliced matrix can be put to a matrix using `reshape`, but is there an elegant way to do it? Ideally this `r_mat + a` operation can be replace by a user-defined function.

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't have a completely arbitrary user-defined func without looping. You can, however, force users to supply a func that accepts `where` as an argument.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. You already pretty much answered your own question before. Will post momentarily.

Comment: `np.frompyfunc` does create a `ufunc` that takes an `out` and `where`, but the speed is nothing like the builtin `ufunc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can have a vectorized solution with a user defined function, as long as that function it is vectorized to work element-wise on a 1D array (which should be the case for anything written using numpy functions out of the box).

Let's say you have `r_mat` as an `(m, n)` matrix and `a_array` as an `(m,)` vector. You can write your function to accept hooks. Each hook can be a constant or a callable. If it is a callable, it gets called with two arrays of the same length, and must return a third array of the same length. You can change that contract to include indices or whatever you want at will:

```
def f(r_mat, a_array, hook11, hook01, hook10, hook00):
    a = a_array[:, None]  # to column vector

    row_mask = (r_mat.mean(axis=1) > 2)[:,None]
    elem_mask = r_mat >= a

    out = np.empty_like(r_mat)

    def apply_hook(mask, hook):
        r, c = np.nonzero(mask)
        out[r, c] = hook(r_mat[r, c], a_array[r]) if callable(hook) else hook

    apply_hook(row_mask & elem_mask, hook11)
    apply_hook(~row_mask & elem_mask, hook01)
    apply_hook(row_mask & ~elem_mask, hook10)
    apply_hook(~row_mask & ~elem_mask, hook00)

    return out
```

The current configuration in your code would be called like

```
f(r_mat, a_array, np.subtract, np.add, np.nan, 0)
```

Let's say you wanted to do something more complex than `np.subtract`. You could do for example:

```
def my_complicated_func(r, a):
    return np.cumsum(r, a) - 3 * r // a + np.exp(a)

f(r_mat, a_array, my_complicated_func, np.add, np.nan, 0.0)
```

The key is that `my_complicated_func` operates on arrays. It will be passed a subset of the elements of `r_mat` and the elements of `a_array` duplicated as many times as necessary along each row.

You could also do the same thing with the function being aware of the index of each location. Just call `hook` as `hook(r_mat[r, c], a_array[r], r, c)`. Now the hook functions must accept two additional arguments. The original code would be equivalent to

```
f(r_mat, a_array, lambda r, a, *args: np.subtract(r, a), lambda r, a, *args: np.add(r, a), np.nan, 0)
```

Comment: The "hook" method is similar to or a little bit slower than the direct masking method for this example.

Comment: @Gang. It's the price of flexibility. There may be cases when using indices is marginally faster since it doesn't require an extra pass to determine output size. Depends on mask density and input size.